# AWS Redshift DEFAULT TIMESTAMP

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-redshift

I am moving some data from old system to AWS -- and I am following the current protocol:

- Create new tables
- Load data in buckets
- Copy from bucket to table

This works great so far, but I am having an issue with empty TIMESTAMPS (some versions of my dates are unavailable -- so I have them set to a default date on my old version, but on the new version, they are being loaded as NULL)

For each time NULL appears in my aws date column, I want to replace it with '0000-00-00 00:00:00' for example.  This is crucial so that I can run an EXCEPT function on the two tables (old & new) to verify the robustness of the process.

I have tried explicit commands like REPLACE, INSERT,

I have rebuilt the table with date column default '0000-00-00 00:00:00'

No luck so far.  Any help would be great!  Thanks!

Comment: Could you please clarify why you wish to set a fake date, rather than using a `NULL` value? Your queries could simulate the fake date with a `CASE` statement, which would be much more accurate than inserting a fake value where the value is actually unknown. So-called **magic values** are generally discouraged in databases because they require special handling, whereas most systems know how to handle (or ignore) `NULL` values.

Answer (score 0):

If you specify the column as `NOT NULL` then Redshift's `COPY` will replace the `NULL`s with the default value specified on the column (and fail if no default is specified).

Have a look at the section `Load Data from a File with Default Values` in the Redshift docs:  http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_COPY_command_examples.html